# How to make an installer for linux with jar file?

Tags: java, linux, javafx

Issues

1. If the java jdk was not installed on linux os the jar will not run.
2. If run javafx jar in linux it comes an error like this

   `Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application`

Afer , I did this . it worked.

To run a java-fx application using terminal, follow these steps:

Install openjfx (if it is not already installed):
`sudo apt install openjfx`

List the javafx library location: 
`dpkg-query -L openjfx`
The output should be like this:

> .
> /usr
> /usr/share
> /usr/share/doc
> /usr/share/doc/openjfx
> /usr/share/doc/openjfx/TODO.Debian
> /usr/share/doc/openjfx/changelog.Debian.gz
> /usr/share/doc/openjfx/copyright
> /usr/share/openjfx
> /usr/share/openjfx/lib
> /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.properties
> /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.base.jar
> /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.controls.jar
> /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.fxml.jar
> /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.graphics.jar
> /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.media.jar
> /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.swing.jar
> /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.web.jar

Run the jar application *by including the javafx path and modules*:
`java --module-path $PATH_TO_OPENJFX-LIB --add-modules module_1,module_2,module_3,...,module_n -jar $PATH_TO_JAR_FILE`

#### Example:

```
java --module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base,javafx.media,javafx.web,javafx.swing -jar '/home/lotfi/Documents/MyAppfolder/my_application.jar'
```

3. If some times the version of java not same to the jar . The jar will not work.

I want to make an installer for java without the above issues.

**It should work even if the user does not installed java jdk on Linux OS.**

In addition to this , I want to add the app in search option in linux os.

[image: search bar]

How can I make an app like this ?

Help!!!

Comment: `.deb` packages can contain a requirement list which means you should be able to make dpkg install jre + javafx and use its postinstall script to create a script file to launch the app with the correct parameters. (Cannot write a full answer though, since I currently only create packages from cmake C(++) projects)

Comment: @fabian Can you give more information?

Comment: Have you considered this, https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin you can make a jlink version with a launcher script.

Comment: @matt  your answer used for javafx. Answer  for issue 1 and 3.

Comment: @Pradeep I don't know what you mean. The javafx maven plugin will create a jlink that includes a jre with the required modules. So it actually satisfies 1 and 3 also.

Comment: How it solve all the issues?       Can you explain?

Comment: If you have a problem with the installation of software on Unbuntu, your should consider asking your question on https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a shell script at the beginning of your jar, where you will put all your logic from 1), 2) and 3) and start the jvm after that.

```
#!/bin/sh
....
java -jar "$0"
exit
%zip content begins here%
```

And start it as `$ ./your.jar`

You can use [makeself-maven-plugin](https://github.com/hazendaz/makeself-maven-plugin) for that.

As well `spring-boot-maven-plugin` has this feature with `embeddedLaunchScript` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html

Comment: Can you give more information for issue 1,2 and 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple tools for java to accomplish this. [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jlink.html) allows you to package a jre with your java files. There is a [maven plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) specifically for accomplishing this task.

If you already have a working maven/javafx setup, then all you need to do is add the plugin to your `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.4</version>
       <configuration>
       <mainClass>modulename/com.example.Main</mainClass>
       <launcher>nametolaunch</launcher>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then when you build your project.

```
mvn javafx:jlink
```

It will compile your project, and create the jlink. Inside of the `target` folder you'll have a folder `image`, that contains everything you need. You can zip that up and use it on any compatible platform.

To run the application `image/bin/nametolaunch`.

Comment: Can you give a step by step tutorial ?